# How to send notification (email) to API subscribers in WSO2 Api Manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is there a way to send a notification to all the API subscribers?

In the documentation there is a guide on how to do it just for a new API version, but it would be really useful to use WSO2 API Manager for other communications too

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in wso2 api manager, by default you can enabled notifications so that subscribers will know that a new api version is available. If you requirement is different you can extend  `org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.notification.Notifier` Abstract class and write a custom class

for more information check [this link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Enabling+Notifications)

Answer (score 0):

You can send an email when there is a new version of the API. Instructions are in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Enabling+Notifications

In addition to that, if you use workflows, then you can write your own implementation to send an email when workflows are completed. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Managing+Workflow+Extensions